# Static assertion if one std::array is a subset of the other

Tags: c++, constexpr, constexpr-function

I'm using two constexpr std::array:

```
constexpr std::array full = { 1,2,3 };
constexpr std::array subset = { 3 };
```

I would like to static assert if the second is a subset of the first.

In the above example, the assertion should succeed, and in the following, it supposes to fail:

```
constexpr std::array full = { 1,2,3 };
constexpr std::array subset = { 3, 4 };
```

I wrote a working constexpr function:

```
constexpr bool isSubset(decltype(full)& a, decltype(subset)& b)
{
    for (const auto& subsetElement : b) {
        bool found = false;
        for (const auto& fullElement : a) {
            if (subsetElement == fullElement) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But I wondered if there is another, more straightforward (without decltype, maybe without constexpr function?) way of doing it (latest CPP).

Comment: It looks like what you need is [`ranges::includes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/includes).

Comment: Sidenote, you could've used `auto` instead of `decltype(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you can `std::ranges::sort` both ranges and then apply[`std::ranges::includes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/includes):

> Returns true if the sorted range [first2, last2) is a subsequence of the sorted range [first1, last1).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1Wjebe9xY):

```
constexpr bool is_subset(auto a, auto b) {
    std::ranges::sort(a);
    std::ranges::sort(b);
    return std::ranges::includes(a, b);
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::array full = { 1,3,2 };
    constexpr std::array subset = { 3, 2 };

    static_assert(is_subset(full, subset), "Has to be a subset");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the elements order is not the same..

Comment: see the edit, now it will work for any ordering.

Comment: But it will require a sort; no way avoiding it?

Comment: for `std::includes` yes, you need to sort it. I am pretty confident you won't get any more efficient than this.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a nest for-loop, or sorting both array, you can also just sort the longer one, and loop on the other one while performing a binary search:

```cpp
constexpr bool isSubset(auto sup, auto sub)
{
    if (sub.size() > sup.size()) return false;
    std::ranges::sort(sup);
    return std::ranges::all_of(sup, 
        [&](auto i){ return std::ranges::binary_search(sub, i); }
    );
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `sup` be ordered too? For std::binary_search to succeed, the range *sup* must be at least partially ordered with respect to *i* (I edited the quote from cppreference to mention `sup` and `i`).

Comment: @rturrado Edited. Should be sorting the longer one instead.

Comment: Thanks! And good point, yes. You don't need to sort both.